# Wordpress - Add post Title to entry_meta function

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add the post title to the entry_meta() function in the TwentySixteen Wordpress theme, in the template-tags.php file. I would like it to print before the author info. but after the avatar image.

basically just before the "screen-reader-text" span.

The function part:

```
if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) {
    $author_avatar_size = apply_filters( 'twentysixteen_author_avatar_size', 205 );
    printf( '<span class="byline"><span class="author vcard">%1$s<span class="screen-reader-text">%2$s </span> <a class="url fn n" href="%3$s">%4$s</a></span></span>',
        get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), $author_avatar_size ),
        _x( 'Author', 'Used before post author name.', 'twentysixteen' ),
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
        get_the_author()
    );
}
```

Adding the_title() in the printf doesn't really work. So not sure how to approach this.

Thank you for anyone thats willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

added the get_the_title() and called it in with %5$s

```
if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) {
    $author_avatar_size = apply_filters( 'twentysixteen_author_avatar_size', 205 );
    printf( '<span class="byline"><span class="author vcard">%1$s<h1 class="entry-title">%5$s</h1><span class="screen-reader-text">%2$s </span> <a class="url fn n" href="%3$s">%4$s</a></span></span>',
        get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), $author_avatar_size ),
        _x( 'Author', 'Used before post author name.', 'twentysixteen' ),
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
        get_the_author(),
        get_the_title()
    );
}
```